# Is there a way to check the size of a Cloud Firestore collection using Security Rules?

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

In my app, each user has a document in the users collection of my database. Under each user's document, there is a subcollection for that user's uploaded foods. By default, I want to limit it so that the user cannot add more than 25 foods to their personal subcollection. Is there a way to check via Security Rules if the collection size is <= 25?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible in security rules.

If you want a document count, you will have to manage one of your own in a single document.  Then you could write rules to check against the count that you manage in that document.

Comment: now it is possible with a regular client query. - [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/aggregation-queries)

Comment: now, can we apply in firestore security rule ?